# Reuse code in a unit test using several Service References (different types, same method names)

Tags: c#, wcf, unit-testing, code-reuse

I have VS 2012 , .NET 4.5, and Unit test project with 5 Service References to Wcf Services.

This Wcf Services implements contracts with the same name for contract.

I have 5 methods for unit testing. The code is the same unless new instruction for create the object (5 types different)

```
    var svc = new SvcReferenceServiceOdpNet.ServiceOdpNetClient();
    var svc = new SvcReferenceServiceOdpNetx86.ServiceOdpNetClient();
    var svc = new SvcReferenceServiceOdpNet_IISHosted.ServiceOdpNetClient();
    var svc = new SvcReferenceServiceOdpNetx64_IISHosted.ServiceOdpNetClient();
    var svc = new SvcReferenceServiceOdpNet_IISHosted_Net40.ServiceOdpNetClient();
```

this code is common

```
    var res = svc.GetTestOdpNetQuery(DataUtils.Select_Sysdate);
```

Method GetTestOdpNetQuery with the same name, svc.GetTestOdpNetQuery, considering that svc variable corresponds to one of 5 types differents.

Any way for sharing code and reuse, and avoid code duplication?

```
[TestMethod]
public void Get_Data_de_OdpNet_con_service_AnyCPU()
{
    var svc = new SvcReferenceServiceOdpNet.ServiceOdpNetClient();
    var res = svc.GetTestOdpNetQuery(DataUtils.Select_Sysdate);
    Assert.IsNotNull(res, "Null Value");

    TestContext.WriteLine("Result: ");
    TestContext.WriteLine(res);
    Assert.IsFalse(res.StartsWith("ERROR"), "Error found ERROR");
}

[TestMethod]
public void Get_Data_de_OdpNet_con_service_x86()
{
    var svc = new SvcReferenceServiceOdpNetx86.ServiceOdpNetClient();
    var res = svc.GetTestOdpNetQuery(DataUtils.Select_Sysdate);
    Assert.IsNotNull(res, "Null Value");

    TestContext.WriteLine("Result: ");
    TestContext.WriteLine(res);
    Assert.IsFalse(res.StartsWith("ERROR"), "Error found ERROR");
}

[TestMethod]
public void Get_Data_de_OdpNet_con_service_AnyCPU_hosted_en_IIS()
{
    var svc = new SvcReferenceServiceOdpNet_IISHosted.ServiceOdpNetClient();
    var res = svc.GetTestOdpNetQuery(DataUtils.Select_Sysdate);
    Assert.IsNotNull(res, "Null Value");

    TestContext.WriteLine("Result: ");
    TestContext.WriteLine(res);
    Assert.IsFalse(res.StartsWith("ERROR"), "Error found ERROR");
}


[TestMethod]
public void Get_Data_de_OdpNet_con_service_x64_hosted_en_IIS()
{
    var svc = new SvcReferenceServiceOdpNetx64_IISHosted.ServiceOdpNetClient();
    var res = svc.GetTestOdpNetQuery(DataUtils.Select_Sysdate);
    Assert.IsNotNull(res, "Null Value");

    TestContext.WriteLine("Result: ");
    TestContext.WriteLine(res);
    Assert.IsFalse(res.StartsWith("ERROR"), "Error found ERROR");
}


[TestMethod]
public void Get_Data_de_OdpNet_con_service_AnyCPU_hosted_en_IIS_Net40()
{
    var svc = new SvcReferenceServiceOdpNet_IISHosted_Net40.ServiceOdpNetClient();
    var res = svc.GetTestOdpNetQuery(DataUtils.Select_Sysdate);
    Assert.IsNotNull(res, "Null Value");

    TestContext.WriteLine("Result: ");
    TestContext.WriteLine(res);
    Assert.IsFalse(res.StartsWith("ERROR"), "Error found ERROR");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Reflection is one option. But a better solution would be delegates.

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void Get_Data_de_OdpNet_con_service_AnyCPU()
    {
        var svc = new SvcReferenceServiceOdpNet.ServiceOdpNetClient();
        DoTest(svc.GetTestOdpNetQuery, DataUtils.Select_Sysdate);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void Get_Data_de_OdpNet_con_service_x86()
    {
     var svc = new SvcReferenceServiceOdpNetx86.ServiceOdpNetClient();
     DoTest(svc.GetTestOdpNetQuery, DataUtils.Select_Sysdate);
    }

    // repeat this test method pattern for all 5 service references and call
    // the DoTest method.

    private void DoTest(Func<DateTime, string> func, DateTime sysDate)
    {
        var res = func(sysDate);
        Assert.IsNotNull(res, "Null Value");

        TestContext.WriteLine("Result: ");
        TestContext.WriteLine(res);
        Assert.IsFalse(res.StartsWith("ERROR"), "Error found ERROR");
    }
```